# How to add line+text outside of graph bounds using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add some additional information too some graphs of mine using matplotlib, but have been unable to figure out how to add two additional elements, a vertical line 1 xtick *outside* of the box, and a text box both next and below said line. I've written up some code for how I want the graph itself to look, but can't figure out how to finish up the final steps. I've attached screenshots of how the graph currently looks [image: Current graph]

versus approximately how I want the graph to look [image]

I currently have the code shown below:

```
def scatter_custom(x, y, index, timepoints):
    '''
    parameters for generate_delta_plots
    generates custom scatterplot with line of best fit 
    '''
    sns.scatterplot(data=None, x=x, y=y, alpha = 0.5, color = 'blue')
    plt.title(index)
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Accuracy')

    #Adds timepoints to x axis
    data_t = []
    for t in timepoints:
        data_t.append(t.partition("_")[0])
    plt.xticks(x, data_t)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)

    #Adds coloration during stress period
    stress_period = []
    t = 0
    while t < len(timepoints):
        if "_stress" in str(timepoints[t]):
            stress_period.append(t)
        t+=1
    plt.axvspan(float(stress_period[0])-0.2, float(stress_period[-1])+0.2, color='red', alpha=0.3)
    
    #Adds line of best fit to model correlation over time
    plt.plot(np.unique(x), np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 1))(np.unique(x)), color='rebeccapurple')
    plt.show()

    return 0
```

which produces the current output shown above. I've tried adding in lines and texts manually, but they end up shifting the box or are inconsistent across iteractions. For reference the x and y params are just values, the index param is just the graph title, and the timepoints param is a list of values with names like "M2_poststress_GLU"

Comment: For lines, using `ax = plt.gca()` : `ax.plot(..., transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), 
 clip_on=False)`.  Or `transform=ax.transAxes`.  See [the transformations tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/artists/transforms_tutorial.html). Similar for `ax.text(..., transform=...)`.  Note that your question would be easier to answer if you'd add explicit reproducible test data, including a good description of how you want to position everything.

Comment: I wasn't really sure how to describe the positioning, so I edited a photo too show that. I'm trying to get the bottom photo from the code. With test data any data that satisfies the basic requirements of the function would work but really the question is more general, I'll read over what you sent thanks, though I haven't been able to figure it out

Comment: A description as "x and y" are just values, is really too vague.  With example data it would become clearer whether they are strings, integers, floats, or something else. Making your question too general, usually doesn't help, as often the approach can change significantly.